# I am getting an error using LOAD in neo4j. What's my error?

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to load data into neo4j using a local csv on my system:

```
    USING PERIODIC COMMIT
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/Users/jlujan/Desktop/northwind/customers.csv" AS row
    CREATE (:Customer {CustomerID: row.CustomerID, CompanyName: row.CompanyName,
    ContactName: row.ContactName, ContactTitle: row.ContactTitle,
    Address: row.Address, City: row.City, Region: row.Region, PostalCode: row.PostalCode, Country: row.Country, Phone: row.Phone, Fax: row.Fax});
```

Every time I get this error: Couldn't load the external resource at: `file:/var/lib/neo4j/import/Users/jlujan/Desktop/northwind/customers.csv`

I think it's a URL issue, but I'm not exactly sure what. Please help!

Comment: where is your csv located? for  local you have to use "file:///C:/" start from the C

Comment: my csv is on my desktop. I've tried that and I still get the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using Neo4j 3? 
You'll find a setting in `neo4j.conf` like this

```
# This setting constrains all `LOAD CSV` import files to be under the `import` directory. Remove or uncomment it to
# allow files to be loaded from anywhere in filesystem; this introduces possible security problems. See the `LOAD CSV`
# section of the manual for details.
dbms.directories.import=import
```

If you remove this/comment it, Neo4j should allow loading files from anywhere in the system